# Pandora starts playing, un-prompted, in middle of the night

Tags: pandora

Samsung GALAXY S-6 with operating system 6.0.1. I use the sleep function on Pandora and it works well. However, the application starts unprompted at random times during the night. Not good, solution?

Comment: Do you have any Bluetooth devices paired that have the ability to start media playback?

Comment: I had this happen for awhile, Pandora would just start playing at random... as @Bort mentioned, it was my BT headset. For some reason while charging it would sort of turn itself on momentarily at times for some unknown reason, starting media playback. Turning the BlueTooth off at night on my phones fixed the problem, and after replacing my old Plantronics headset with a new one, it stopped occurring, although at times if I have 2 phones active at one time, and the right circumstances occur well hanging up a call on phone 2, Pandora still starts at random.

Comment: I do not have any bluetooth devices connected and the bluetooth function is not activated on the phone.

Comment: My HTC 10 has started doing this. Seems to always happen right around 1:30am. I do have a Moto360 attached. I have checked both the phone and the watch for any alarms and such. Any ideas?

Comment: I have this problem and I don't have Bluetooth on ever. Went off at 2am while I was sleeping! Galaxy s5.

Comment: I just had to uninstall it since I couldn't figure it out. Not only did it start spontaneously, I couldn't even turn it off because it didn't show up in my list of running apps. It was like it was on, but not on. I would have to power down my whole phone to get it to stop. It's not worth the trouble, there are way too many other music apps out there to be dealing with this. No Bluetooth devices connected at the time and also in an area with a very weak WiFi signal.

Comment: My phone​ just woke me up because it decided to play Pandora really loud at 11.30pm. the app didn't show up im my open app list either and I had to open the app and shut it then to stop it. Plus the volume was different as it played really loudly despite the volume bring set much lower when I went back in to check​.
My phone is a Samsung s6 which recently updated to Android 7 nougat

Comment: @acejavelin you should make that an answer