# Why does Pandora start automatically at random?

Tags: pandora

My relatives and now I too have an issue with Pandora starting automatically at random. One has a Samsung Galaxy S20, another has a Motorola, and I have a Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra.

On all three phones, at random times of the day/night, the app will automatically start playing music. Usually happens when charging, but not always. Just happened now with it in my phone pouch on my hip. It also happened the last 2 nights around 4 am, waking me up. And the occurrence for all three of us is getting more frequent. One already uninstalled the app, and another is going to uninstall it too. I have been waiting patiently for a fix, but I'm about to give up on it as well. Can't afford for it to wake me up at 4 am all the time.

When this happens, the phone says there are no running apps and thus I can't close it or stop it normally. I have to "force stop" the app every time. The Bluetooth is turned off on my phone, but I can't say for sure about the others.

We have tried removing it and re-downloading a fresh start, didn't help. We have tried powering off the phone for 15 minutes, didn't help. We have searched through forums and found many people with the same issue, but no one has a fix or even an acknowledgment of an issue that's being worked on.

Comment: When talking about a third party app please always include a link to the app in Google Play Store.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There's an existing question about the same issue: [Pandora starts playing, un-prompted, in middle of the night](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/142886/44325). However, no one really knew the cause. Meanwhile, you might get some hints by [checking the log](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/14430/44325) when it happens.

Comment: From the comments on that question,  the top possibility is faulty headset or ear buds. You should ask their support as well.